# How do I sign up for the bixby developer program?

Tags: bixby

I've seen the bixby personal assistant on samsung phones. Can I develop for it? How do I get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bixby Developer Program is Live now. Please goto [Bixby Developers](https://bixbydevelopers.com/) to check out the latest developments. You can download for both windows as well as mac operating systems. The latest releases for the 4th quarter for Bixby can be seen here - [Bixby Studio Release](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/release-notes/bixby-studio.2018-Q4-Bixby-Studio-Release-Notes)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Bixby Get Started Gude](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/get-started), there you can find lots of useful information for begginers!
Developer Guide posted [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers) contain technical faq anwers.